# How can we get the children(calendardayitem) of parent object(calendarview) in winui?

Tags: windows, winui-3, winui

In UWP,we can fetch the children by FindDescendants<> .But in winui, we can't able to do that.
By doing with visualhelpertree,It always shows zero count in getchildCount() from the calendarview

I just wanted to know how to fetch the children of calendarview .
Also i have tried this but shows me zero child always,

```
    private void FindDescendants1(DependencyObject parent, Type targetType)
        {
            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            itemchange.Text = childrenCount.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child =(CalendarViewDayItem) VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                if (child.GetType() == targetType)
                {
                    results.Add(child);
                }
                FindDescendants1(child, targetType);
            }
        }
```

Simply I have created this function to get the child and called,

```
foreach (DependencyObject displayedDay in results)
        {
            //displayedDay = (CalendarViewDayItem)displayedDay;
            CalendarViewDayItem c = displayedDay as CalendarViewDayItem;
            if (_highlightedDates.Contains(c.Date))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Date.ToString());
                //highlight
                c.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            itemchange.Text = c.Date.ToString();
        }
```

But this not getting the child ,results is the list of objects here where it always show me zero .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is that you are calling FindDescendants1() before the control is loaded, in the constructor for example. If your `CalendarView` is in a `Page`, try calling FindDescendants1() in the `Page`'s `Loaded` event.

But there's another problem in you code below.

```cs
var child = (CalendarViewDayItem)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
```

You'll get an exception because you're trying to cast every `DependencyObject` to a `CalendarViewDayItem`. By removing the cast you should get the `CalendarViewItems`. Though, I would make the FinDescendants() static and just receive the results:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<T> FindDescendantsOfType<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        
        if (child is T hit)
        {
            yield return hit;
        }

        foreach (T? grandChild in FindChildrenOfType<T>(child))
        {
            yield return grandChild;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```cs
this.results = FindChildrenOfType<CalendarViewDayItem>(this.CalendarViewControl);

foreach (var item in this.results)
{
    // Do you work here...
}
```